# Upgrading slackware 12 to 13 causes keyboard and mouse to not work in any window manager?

Tags: kernel, xorg, drivers, x

I'm trying to figure out why my new setup just does not work. I followed the readme instructions in the slackware distribution and upgrade the system.

After upgrade, `xorgconfig` is removed and the only way I could configure video without messing things up is through `xorgsetup` but running that causes a lockup and a blank screen.

So I am able to run any window manager of my choice but as soon as any one starts, the keyboard and mouse do not respond at all. I even try pressing <kbd>numlock</kbd> on the keyboard and the light does not respond. However, in Unix, both items work.

- I tried starting X with `xinit`, and `startx`
- I tried configuring stuff with `Xorg -configure` and `xorgsetup` and they both failed.

The computer is also old (Compaq Presario) Pentium 1.

Is there anything I can do in Unix to fix this or even any patch I can apply to make the keyboard and mouse to work?

Mouse is USB and keyboard is PS/2

Comment: For a machine that old it's best to stick with the old Linux. Or reinstall from scratch, as upgrades are not Linux's strongest part.